# Trying to find the name of a book

Tags: story-identification, powers

Read this book a time ago (3+ years ago) where this organization helps people fight off supernatural beings, I'm pretty sure they were evil spirits, but they fought them with their abilities, and they're always in partners, one with an active member and a passive member, each with different  abilities (such as strengthened senses and energy powers i think), and only the leader of the organization has both passive/active. And the main character is one girl who,is an active member and its her and,her friends rooting out the corruption in the organization itself. Also I'm from the USA and it was in English.

Can anyone help me figure out the title and author of this book?
Thanks so much.

Comment: I've never read the book, but there was a film called Star Wars a while ago that sort of matches.

Comment: What kind of supernatural beings?  What kind of abilities?  Can you narrow the time frame down a little?  (Many 13-year-olds think five years ago was "a long time ago".)  Was the book in English?  What country were you in?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it could be one of the "[Books of the Order](http://www.pjballantine.com/writing/books-of-the-order/)" series by Philippa Ballantine. Deacons of the Order fight "geists" (basically ghosts) in pairs, each of which has an Active (attacking powers) and Sensitive (sensing powers) member.

From the description of *Geist*, the first book in the series, in above link:

> Between the living and the dead is the Order of the Deacons,
>   protectors of the Empire, guardians against possession, sentinels
>   enlisted to ward off the malevolent haunting of the geists…
>
> Among the most powerful of the Order is Sorcha, now thrust into
>   partnership with the novice Deacon, Merrick Chambers. They have been
>   dispatched to the isolated village of Ulrich to aide the Priory with a
>   surge of violent geist activity. With them is Raed Rossin, Pretender
>   to the throne that Sorcha is sworn to protect, and bearer of a
>   terrible curse.
>
> But what greets them in the strange settlement is something far more
>   predatory and more horrifying than any mere haunting. And as she
>   uncovers a tradition of twisted rituals passed down through the dark
>   reaches of history, Sorcha will be forced to reconsider everything she
>   thinks she knows.
>
> And if she makes it out of Ulrich alive, what in Hell is she returning
>   to?